# Store a number of one digit in a vector of char using sprintf

Tags: c, vector, char

c[100] is a vector of char and x is a number between 1 and 9

How can I store x in a given position (n) in c

What I tried is:

```
sprintf(c[n], "%d", x);
```

but it does not work

If I write:

```
sprintf(&c[n], "%d", x);
```

it works fine. Can someone explain to me why is that? Or maybe give me another ideea to solve the problem

Comment: Look at your compiler carefully.  The compiler will tell you exactly what's wrong with the first case (wrong type for first argument).

Comment: Checkout the documentation for the first argument `man sprintf`.

Comment: Is it because the first argument of the function has to be a pointer? So that means that I have to sent the addres of fen[n]?

Comment: sprintf expects a pointer to an address where it can write the string. `c[n]` is not a pointer, it's the value of the character at this address. `&c[n]` is the address. Side note: if x is between 1 and 9 then you don't need sprintf, you can do `c[n] = x + '0'`, but make sure to terminate the string afterwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing to understand is that when you declare `char c[100]`, your program reserves 100 bytes in the stack of the current frame for `c`. (Remember: this means you cannot continue to use `c` after your function returns.)

The main confusion comes when you try to understand the difference between `c` and `&c`. When you use `c`, you will get the address of the first element of `c` and its type is `char[100]`. When you use `&c`, you will get the address of the array `c` and its type is `char (*)[100]`. Confusingly, both *values* are the same.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  char c[100];
  printf(" c: %p\n", c);  // will print (e.g.,):  c: 0x16d30b6c4
  printf("&c: %p\n", &c); // will print (e.g.,): &c: 0x16d30b6c4
  return 0;
}
```

With that said, when you use `c[n]` you get the actual `char` at position *n* of `c`. This is *not* an address; it's the actual byte value. When you use `&c[n]`, you will get the address of position *n* in the array (which is the same as `c + n`).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  char c[100] = "Testing";
  printf(" c: %p\n", c);        // will print (e.g.,) :  c: 0x16d30b6c4
  printf("&c: %p\n", &c);       // will print (e.g.,) : &c: 0x16d30b6c4
  printf(" c[2]: %c\n", c[2]);  // will print (always): s
  printf("&c[2]: %p\n", &c[2]); // will print (e.g.,) : &c[2]: 0x16d30b6c6
  printf("c + 2: %p\n", c + 2); // will print (e.g.,) : c + 2: 0x16d30b6c6
  return 0;
}
```

If you check the [man page for `sprintf()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fprintf.3p.html) you will see the definition is:

```
int sprintf(char *restrict s, const char *restrict format, ...);
```

Ignoring `restrict` which is out of scope for this answer, the type that `sprintf()` expects is `char *` (or a pointer to a `char`). Per example above, the correct way to represent the address of a position of a `char[]` array is `&array[position]`. That's why your `sprintf(&c[n], "%d", x);` works and `sprintf(c[n], "%d", x);` does not.

Finally, always consider using [`snprintf()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fprintf.3p.html) which will prevent writing beyond the boundaries of your `char *` array. Remember to adjust the `size_t n` given to `snprintf()` if your initial `char *restrict s` is not the address of the first byte of the array.

Answer (score 1):

Well `snprintf()` expects pointer to char (`char*`) as first argument. In your 1st example you are passing `char`, which will not work.

The question is if you want to store number (as in integer value, e.g. `1`, `2`, etc.) or digit (as in printable representation of number, e.g. `'1'`, `'2'`, etc.). If it's the number and you are certain that the value is between 1 to 9, then all you need to do is:

```c
c[n] = (char) x;
```

in other case you can do:

```c
c[n] = (char) x + '0';
```

which will effectively convert the `x` to digit. In this case I would recommend to describe such behavior more by encasing the conversion into some function (e.g. `int_to_digit()`) for better readability.